# find instances of a form in vb 2008

Tags: vb.net, forms, instances

```
Dim f as new frmNameHere  
f.show()
```

How do I find all instances of `frmNameHere` created using the above code?

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance!", don't do it next time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example:

```
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
   Dim frm As New frmNameHere()
   frm.Show()
Next
Dim openForms = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmNameHere)()
While openForms.Any()
   openForms.First.Close()
End While
```

Works also without linq, but then you have to iterate through all OpenForms:

```
Dim forms As FormCollection = Application.OpenForms
For Each form As Form In forms
   If TypeOf form Is frmNameHere Then
      'do something with your frmNameHere-Form'
   End If
Next
```